# How to make out @variable and variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To be compatible with other actions.I use `variable`(not `@variable`) in `_show.html.erb`.

```
<p><%= journal.title %></p>
```

But in `show.html.erb`, i can't turn `@variable` into `variable` and render to `_show.html.erb`.

```
<%=render partial: 'show' locals: { journal: @journal }%>

syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER
```

In addition:
How can i make out @variable and variable,then do different things?

```
 @journal = Journal.first
 journal = Journal.first

if is @variable
  do sth
else
  do sth
end
```

Comment: I don't understand your additional question. Why do you want to store the same value in two different variables (a local and an instance variable)? Are you looking for something like `if defined?(@journal)`?

Comment: Yes,thank you vary much.

Comment: This is not a variable problem, your syntax is wrong (hence the syntax error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma and this leads to a `syntax error`. Change

```
<%=render partial: 'show' locals: { journal: @journal }%>
```

to

```
<%= render partial: 'show', locals: { journal: @journal } %>
```

I addition: You can use the `defined?` method to check if a variable is defined, for example:

```
if defined?(@journal)
  # @journal is set
else
  # @journal is not set 
end
```